# ImportError: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda, virtualenv

I've been trying to open up a virtual environment. I can open scrapy from anaconda powershell prompt, but I can't use it in the virtual environment. I have created the environment by using the command:

```
C:\Python310\Scripts\virtualenv.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

I have also started the virtual environment using the command:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
```

But I when I try using this command,

```
scrapy shell
```

it gives this error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\io.py", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)
```

I installed the virtual environment module with this command:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

But there are nothing like "activate.bat" in my scripts folder (C:\Python310\Scripts) instead there is the file "virtualenv.exe". However there is a scripts folder in my virtual environment (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts) which has the file "activate.bat".

How can I fix the error?
Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error but not on windows and I solved it by rebuilding Python, so I suggest you re-install Python. Also, I suggest not mixing pure Python with Anaconda. Did this work with another version of Python?
Finally, I cant tell which 3.10 you are using but I would use the latest 3.10.2.
if you need more help then you need to add more info.
You may like to check the scrapy [docs.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)

Answer (score 0):

When creating and switching between venv, please remember Environment Variables
PATH, PYTHONHOME ...

1. Are you pointing at C:\ProgramData\anaconda3? or C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\py39?
2. Have you restarted command prompt after Edit System Environment Variables?